# Launch Wikitude view controller from Xamarin Forms application

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

I have as part of my project the Wikitude SDK installed. I've brought over the storyboard and placed it within my iOS specific code. I've also brought over the view controller code.

In my PCL, I have a simple interface set up with a single void method.

Within the platform code (for iOS), the interface is implemented like this

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(WikitudeView))]
namespace turtlewax.iOS
{
public class WikitudeView : IWikitude
{
    public void LaunchWikitude()
    {
        var composer = new WikitudeVC(IntPtr.Zero);

        var rootController = UIApplication.SharedApplication.KeyWindow.RootViewController;
        var navcontroller = rootController as UINavigationController;
        if (navcontroller != null)
            rootController = navcontroller.VisibleViewController;
        rootController.PresentViewController(composer, true, () =>
            {
                composer.StartAR();
            });
    }
}
}
```

The problem comes when I attempt to show the VC. Xamarin crashes out with the following error

`2015-11-04 16:26:10.896 turtlewax.iOS[864:875807] critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
2015-11-04 16:26:10.896 turtlewax.iOS[864:875807] critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) ObjCRuntime.Messaging.void_objc_msgSendSuper_IntPtr_bool_IntPtr (intptr,intptr,intptr,bool,intptr) <0xffffffff>
2015-11-04 16:26:10.897 turtlewax.iOS[864:875807] critical:   at UIKit.UIViewController.PresentViewController (UIKit.UIViewController,bool,System.Action) [0x0007e] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/2356/9ce9e8b9/source/maccore/src/build/ios/native/UIKit/UIViewController.g.cs:798`

Using the interface route for injection works fine on Android.

I'm stumped here - any help on launching the wikitude VC from my Xam.Forms app would be appreciated.